# curl / xargs / influxdb - generate cli argument from text file

Tags: curl, xargs, influxdb

I have the file `data.txt` that looks like this:

```
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274130
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274133
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274136
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274139
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274142
```

I need to generate this InfluxDB command based on the contents of `data.txt`:

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://192.168.99.100:8086/write?db=ecg&precision=ms' --data-binary 'ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274130
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274133
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274136
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274139
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274142'
```

This is my first attempt at a solution (with `xargs`):

```
$ cat data.txt | xargs -0 -t curl -i -XPOST 'http://192.168.99.100:8086/write?db=ecg&precision=ms' --data-binary 
curl -i -XPOST http://192.168.99.100:8086/write?db=ecg&precision=ms --data-binary ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274130
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274133
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274136
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274139
ecgtimeseries value=-0.145 1441114274142
```

However, because I don't know how to also generate those apostrophes that enclose the data, the command doesn't behave as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass a file to InfluxDB using `curl`, use the `@<filename>` syntax as described in the "Write a Batch of Points with curl" section of the [write syntax doc](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/write_protocols/write_syntax.html).

For example: 
`curl -i -XPOST 'http://192.168.99.100:8086/write?db=ecg&precision=ms' --data-binary @data.txt`

The `@<filename>` syntax is part of `curl`, so if you have difficulties please check the `curl` manpage. Note that your file must not have carriage returns `0x0D`, only linefeeds `0x0A`. If you aren't on a Windows machine you should be fine.